# How to open internal MediaWiki links with their full URL from within Vim?

Tags: external-command

I have a file in Mediawiki format, containing internal links (in a Mediawiki installation)

```
* [[Topic A]]
* [[Topic B]]
* [[Vim]]
```

(The asterisks are how MediaWiki lists are formatted, they are not mandatory, as the solution should work on `[[Topic A]] [[Topic B]] [[Vim]]` as well.)

I want to open these links with their *full* URL, e.g. `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim`.

1. Can I e.g. use something like
   <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> (which works on complete URLs) for an individual list entry, but having it complete the rest of the URL and opening it the browser?
2. Is there a solution to open *all* listed elements at once?

Thank you.

Comment: We’d need to understand the URL construction scheme. Is the format guaranteed for the links? Is that a list of links (i.e., are the asterisks always present)?

Answer (score 2):

`gx` is normally processed by `netrw` plugin. You can try to plug into it like this:

```
function g:ExpandWiki(expr)
    " perform standard expand() for netrw
    let l:url = expand(a:expr)
    " check if it looks like "wiki" URL
    let l:wiki = matchstr(l:url, '\[\[\zs.*\ze\]\]')
    " root should be patched to match your installation
    return empty(l:wiki) ? l:url : 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' . l:wiki
endfunction

" redefine <Plug>NetrwBrowseX to use our custom expansion
let rhs = maparg('<Plug>NetrwBrowseX', 'n')
if !empty(rhs)
    exe 'nn <silent><Plug>NetrwBrowseX' substitute(rhs, 'expand(', 'ExpandWiki(', '')
else
    echoerr 'Netrw is not found!'
    echoerr 'Perhaps, you may want to run this code from ~/.vim/after/plugin'
endif
```